# How to access the String when creating a new method for String.prototype in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn how to add new methods in the String.prototype in JavaScript. But I can't figure out a way on how to access the string specified in the new method:

```
String.prototype.new_method = function(){ THE_STRING; };
```

So that it will return "abc" when I call it:

```
"abc".new_method();
```

I know this can easily be done by doing:

```
function returnstring(str){
   return str;
}
```

But I really want to learn how prototypes in JavaScript works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use 'this' to access the string:

```
String.prototype.new_method = function(){ alert(this); };
"abc123".new_method();
```

​

Answer (score 0):

You can access the string with `this`.